# Is there a more optimized way of searching with LINQ to Objects?

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following DTO and LINQ query:

```
public class DupeCheckRecordsDto
{
    public string A_HOMEPHONE_ { get; set; }
    public string A_WORKPHONE_ { get; set; }
    public string A_MOBILEPHONE_ { get; set; }
    public string A_SSNO_ { get; set; }
    public string A_EMAILADDRESS_ { get; set; }
}


var phones =
    new[]
    {
        leadApplication.CellPhone,
        leadApplication.DayPhone,
        leadApplication.EveningPhone,
        leadApplication.OtherPhone
    };

List<DupeCheckRecordsDto> listOfDays = _backEndRepository.DupeCheckRecords(daysBack).ToList();

bool matchFound = false;

foreach (var phone in phones)
{
    bool result = listOfDays.Any(p => p.A_HOMEPHONE_ == phone || p.A_MOBILEPHONE_ == phone || p.A_WORKPHONE_ == phone);
    if (!result) continue;
    matchFound = true; 
    break;
}
```

The materialization of the listOfDays is fast, so I'm not looking for optimization there, it's the usage of the Any and the looping construct that concern me.

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Change this:

```
var phones =
    new[]
    {
        leadApplication.CellPhone,
        leadApplication.DayPhone,
        leadApplication.EveningPhone,
        leadApplication.OtherPhone
    };
```

To:

```
var phones = new HashSet<string>
    {
        leadApplication.CellPhone,
        leadApplication.DayPhone,
        leadApplication.EveningPhone,
        leadApplication.OtherPhone
    };
```

And then your LINQ query becomes:

```
bool result = listOfDays.Any(p => phones.Contains(p.A_HOMEPHONE)
    || phones.Contains(p.A_MOBILEPHONE)
    || phones.Contains(p.A_WORKPHONE_));
```

You don't need the `foreach (var phone in phones)`. The above will search all four in a single pass.

The point here is that you'll only have to scan the list ones. `HashSet.Contains` is an O(1) operation. So you only look at every record once.

In your original, you're looking at every record four times.

If you leave `phones` as an array, doing `phones.Contains` will have to compare against each item in the list. With a `HashSet`, it does a single lookup.

How much faster that will be is a bit unclear, because the `phones` list is kind of small.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to eliminate the foreach syntax but I would expect it to perform roughly the same.

```
bool matchFound = listOfDays.Any(p =>
  phones.Contains(p.A_HOMEPHONE_) || 
  phones.Contains(p.A_MOBILEPHONE) ||
  phones.Contains(p.A_WORKPHONE_));
```

Answer (score 1):

what about this:

```
 bool matchFound = listOfDays.Any(p => phones.Any(phone=> p.A_HOMEPHONE_ == phone || p.A_MOBILEPHONE_ == phone || p.A_WORKPHONE_ == phone));

 bool matchFound = listOfDays.Any(p => phones.Contains(p.A_HOMEPHONE_) ||phones.Contains(p.A_MOBILEPHONE_) ||phones.Contains(p.A_WORKPHONE_ ));
```